# Azure Search DataSource with on-premise SQL Server and best practices?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Documentation on Azure Search says I can use Azure Sql server as a datasource(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers-2015-02-28/). Can I do the same with an on-premise SQL server?

I have a typical relational structure like

User Table -> Address Table 
User Table -> UserDetails table 
 etc..

All linked to each other via foreign keys. My search should end up with an UserId, so I can link to my UserDetailsPage.aspx?UserId=xxx

What will be the best suggested way to build the datasource? Should I Create a view and apply change tracking on it? or Should I create a different datasource for each table and sync the concerned index?

Please shed some light on best practices in a typical relational database scenario.

Answer (score 2):

you would need to allow the IP address of your search service to connect to your on-prem DB.
In terms of view vs. multiple indexers targeting the same index - both approaches might work. What info will your users be searching on - address, details, or both? If it's only one of those, then you wouldn't have to index both tables.

Keep in mind that if you decide to index a view joining both tables, you won't be able to use SQL integrated change tracking, and will have to rely on a rowversion or timestamp column in the view.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Yes we want to search on both. I don't have last-updated timestamps on some of the tables. Is row Version something that sql server automatically generates and updates on chages?

Comment: Yes, if you add a column with rowversion datatype, SQL Server will automatically update it every time you update a row.

However, if you set up two datasources / indexers (one for Address table, one for UserDetails table) both writing to a single search index, you can still rely on SQL integrated change tracking. When indexer inserts a document into an index, it uses merge action, which means that you can do partial updates of the documents. Try that approach first since it doesn't require any changes to your table schema or creating additional views.

Comment: Can I be able to setup change tracking on all the tables that sync's and use different data sources to each table to update the column individually ?

Comment: @Avinash - Please don't ask additional questions in comments. Ask a new question.

Comment: @Avinash, yes. You would need to enable change tracking at the DB level and for each table. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713(v=sql.105).aspx for detailed instructions.

Comment: Isn't the following a concern, though? "Q: Can I use Azure SQL indexer with SQL databases running on-premises?A: We do not recommend or support this, as doing this would require you to open your databases to Internet traffic." https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers-2015-02-28/