# Configure azure search IP to connect to On-prem DB

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cognitive-search, indexer

I am using Indexer to load data in Azure Index. I want to use on-premise database to copy data in azure index. I don't want to use ADF.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881304/azure-search-datasource-with-on-premise-sql-server-and-best-practices) I found that i need to allow azure search IP to connect to on-prem db. But I don't know how to configure that?

Answer (score 3):

This is not recommended. From the [Azure SQL indexer FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#faq):

> Q: Can I use Azure SQL indexer with SQL databases running on-premises?
>
> Not directly. We **do not recommend or support a direct connection, as
>   doing so would require you to open your databases to Internet traffic**.
>   Customers have succeeded with this scenario using bridge technologies
>   like Azure Data Factory. For more information, see [Push data to an
>   Azure Search index using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-search-connector).

We would be interested to know why you cannot/don't want to use ADF. Please send your feedback to eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain.

If you still want to set a direct connection, follow [Configure a connection from an Azure Search indexer to SQL Server on an Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-iaas-to-azure-search-using-indexers). In particular, on IP addresses:

> Restrict access to the search service IP address We strongly recommend
>   that you restrict the access to the IP address of your search service
>   in the ACL instead of making your SQL Azure VMs wide open to any
>   connection requests. You can easily find out the IP address by pinging
>   the FQDN (for example, your-search-service-name.search.windows.net)
>   of your search service.

Comment: Thanks,Eugene. The reason that i don't want to use ADF is because my requirement is to get the latest data in every 5 minutes or may be less. But i can't schedule ADF for less than 15 minutes.